# Load filenames into array without directory name or extension

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to load filenames to an array in bash. Currently, I'm using:

```
testarr=(csv/*.csv)
```

Which is giving me elements like

```
csv/filename.csv
```

How can I add only 'filename' to the array?

Thanks!

Comment: @lurker, your suggestion is buggy as-amended with filenames with spaces or, particularly, whitespace-surrounded wildcards. `foo=( $(...) )` is an antipattern in general for just that reason: Expansion contents are string-split and glob-expanded going into the array, meaning that they may not match their original form. (Also, a stream of filenames separated by newlines is intrinsically unreliable since filenames may themselves contain newline literals).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest thing is first to add the entire name, then strip the parts you don't want using [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
testarr=( csv/*.csv )            # load literal filenames
testarr=( "${testarr[@]##*/}" )  # strip off directory names
testarr=( "${testarr[@]%.csv}" ) # strip off extensions
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done also using basename -a:

```
testarr=($(basename -a csv/*.csv))
```

Comment: This is buggy: Look at what it does if any of the filenames contain spaces (or, most particularly, whitespace-surrounded wildcards).

Comment: `touch 'csv/hello * world.csv'` to emulate the latter case for testing. `touch $'csv/hello\nworld.csv'` is another corner case to note.